# How to use session.post_send with boofuzz

Tags: fuzzing

Doing blackbox Rest API fuzzing, I would like to verify after each fuzzing request that a non fuzzed request are still OK as I have no access to the target. Is session.post_send can be used and how ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, post_send can be used this way. See [Session.post_send documentation](http://boofuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/Session.html#boofuzz.Session.post_send).

For example, you might add the following after line 50 of [this example file](https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz-ftp/blob/cfdbce3771cbd4ac93165f6b6c26e4041b8ba307/ftp.py#L50):

```
session.post_send = my_post_send
```

Of course, you will need to define `my_post_send`, for example:

```
def my_post_send(target, fuzz_data_logger, session, sock, *args, **kwargs):
    target.send('some data')
    response = target.recv(10000)
    fuzz_data_logger.log_check('Checking response data ....')
    # if failure is found:
    fuzz_data_logger.log_fail('SUT responded with ___ indicating catastrophic failure')
```

See also documentation for [Target](http://boofuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/Target.html#boofuzz.Target) and [IFuzzLogger](http://boofuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/logging.html#logging-interface).